# Get index of last created page in SharePoint 2010 library

Tags: c#, linq, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, caml

I am trying to get index of last created page in SharePoint 2010 library using below code:

```
int pageIndex = wikiPages.RootFolder.Files.Count - 1;      
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File wikiFile = wikiPages.RootFolder.Files[pageIndex];
```

but it is returning me the index of page after sorting in alphabetical manner.
Any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### How to retrieve the *last* List Item using CSOM

The following example demonstrates how to retrieve the last List Item with associated File that could be used for retrieving last wiki file as well:

```
var wikiPages = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
var query = new CamlQuery
                {
                    ViewXml = "<View><Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ID' Ascending='FALSE'/></OrderBy></Query><RowLimit>1</RowLimit></View>"
                };
var items = wikiPages.GetItems(query);
ctx.Load(items, icol => icol.Include(i => i.File));
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
if (items.Count == 1)
{
    var pageFile = items[0].File; 
    Console.WriteLine(pageFile.Name);
}
```